# PHP parse data into an array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I am using a API to get some data from curl. Response i get is like:

```
{
  "abc": 123,
  "zxc": 122339900,
  "cui": "usd",
  "cumer": "wXl3tAPXCM",
  "fee": 0,
  "live": false,
  "object": "test",
  "paid": true,
  "sss": {
    "qwe": "4242",
    "wer": "sss",
    "mkm": "isa"
  }
}
```

In which form it is ? how can i parse it to get same values in an array for the further process?
Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$new = json_decode($returnData);
```

This is a json, which can be converted into PHP array by the function [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: hey thanks. it was a silly question. I should have known, used JSON alot of times but somehow didn't recognized. Sorry and thanks again. :)

Answer (score 2):

if the response is `JSON` you can use:

```
json_decode($response, true);
```

the second parameter forces the result to be an associative array.

[php.net documentation](http://php.net/json_decode)

Answer (score 2):

The response is in [JSON](http://www.json.org/)

It's becoming the standard for transferring data from one machine to other because it is bandwidth friendly and language independent.

To translate the JSON into PHP array you can use PHP's native [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$new = json_decode($returnData, TRUE);
```

Just be sure to give last param TRUE or you will get PHP Object instead of array.

Answer (score 1):

This is a json string. You have to decode like below & you will get an array.

`$your_array = json_decode($your_String);`

Answer (score 1):

The data is in 'JSON' format and you should have to use `json_decode()` function to decode the data..

Answer (score 0):

This response is json. Use json_decode e.g.

```
$myarray = json_decode ($response, True);
```

Where the second argument True tells the function to produce an associative array.